# How can I view a program context menu's command?

Tags: windows

I downloaded a program. Its context menu works fine in Windows XP Explorer, but in Windows 2008, the context menu doesn't appear. It looks like the shell extension on the software isn't compatible with Windows 2008.

It's freeware and problem is that author doesn't support this software any more. So, I am thinking to add context menu manually on Windows 2008 with some custom software.

But i need to know what the command is to set the context menu on Windows XP.

Does any one know how to see what command it's run under context menu, is there any software can help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 2008?  Context menus that are managed by 32-bit shell extension DLLs will not work in 64-bit versions of Windows Explorer.  A 64-bit version of the DLL is needed.

Comment: I am running 64bit version, i think you are right, it's 32-bit dll managed, are there any way around i can make it run on 64bit ?

Comment: No. A 32-bit DLL simply cannot be loaded into a 64-bit process, period (and vice versa, a 64-bit DLL with a 32-bit process). You need a 64-bit DLL in this situation. I recently learned that the hard way when I needed to update one of my own 32-bit Shell Extension DLLs for 64-bit Windows. I had no choice but to compile a 64-bit version of it.

Answer (score 2):

[ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) is a free program that allows you to see the context menus entries for programs on your machine.

I'd check out this [article](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm) for adding the custom context menu for win2008. It covers utilities and methods for managing context menus and shell extensions.